# What music streaming app fits my needs on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, streaming, music, internet-radio

I'm looking for an application to stream Internet radio on Ubuntu. I like listening to Radio Paradise while I work. Right now, I'm using Amarok. "Movie Player" sometimes refuses to open the stream, and VLC doesn't keep its window title updated with the currently playing track. Amarok has nice translucent notifications when tracks change, but track changes in streams don't trigger the notifications.

Mostly, I want something that reliably opens streams and makes it easy to see the name of the track that's playing. If it has a built-in directory of streaming radio stations, that would be a big benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about rhythmbox? You can add your own radio station, and it should do the notifications, as well as tell you track names. And, it should've came with ubuntu.

Comment: Oh, maybe it doesn't do notifications or tell you track names. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

[Songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/), built off of Mozilla's XULRunner.  Does everything that iTunes can, and is multiplatform.

Comment: This doesn't show the track name that's playing except buried in its large user interface.